# ASP.net Array List as a data source for Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, data-binding

I am working with an asp.net grid view and i have used an array list of objects as a data source for this gridview.
every thing is ok but I faced some problems when i want to work on this gridview,
I want to to do the following:

1. Hiding a column
2. Change the column header text
3. Add a button to the gridview row and pass a value from the row to another page

thx in advance.

Comment: The title of your question is not related the body of your question. The data source (ArrayList) is not related to the GridView visual manipulations.

Comment: I have bounded the array list to the gridview and it works well. but then I can't handle the columns as i want for example I couldn't hide the column or change its header text and so on

Comment: Why are you using an `ArrayList`?  You shouldn't ever be using it unless you're in C# 1.0.  Use `List` at the very least.

Answer (score 0):

1. Hiding a column: are you using autogenerate columns? or did you add your own columns to the grid?
2. Change the column header text: open the grid columns editor (the little > icon on the upper right corner when you select the gridview)
3. Add a command column from the grid columns editor (step 2 above)

HTH

Jafar

Comment: I have tried to add my own columns but when I bounded the array list it ignores my columns and add the array list columns

Comment: @Hany You need to set `AutoGenerateColumns` to `false` if you define your own columns.

Comment: @Hany if you have your own columns then you need to set the 'DataField' property for each of your columns to bind them. Then you need to call the 'DataBind' function for the grid